# Eclipse; Android; Where is R.id.status?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm doing project with examples. There is **R.id.status** but I cannot find it. Where on earth is it?

These are useful information of me in Manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

and, this is a problem string.

```
TextView status;
status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Is you declare I'd in your layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.id.status` refers to a layout element which has been assigned `android:id="@+id/status"`. Look for it in the layout that you use for the `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Well your question kind of confuses me, "Is Project with examples" some kind of tutorial you are using to learn Android. 
On another note you can find R.id.status in your layout file (that is the file name in your setContentView(R.layout.nameofthelayoutfile). The layout file should be in your res folder if you are using Android Studio Ctrl + Click on the name of the file will take you to the location otherwsie try and read the docs or this tutorial will help you understand how the android project structure is [Android Project Structure](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-project-structure--mobile-12781)